# Authenticating with RSA using JWT on Owin

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, rsa, owin, jwt

Consider this code in my Web API 2 using Owin middleware:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        ConfigureAuthentication(app);
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;    
    }

    private static void ConfigureAuthentication(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var issuer = "<<MyIssuer>>";
        var audience = "<<MyAudience>>";

        const string publicKeyBase64 = "<<MyPublicKeyBase64>>";

        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(publicKeyBase64));

        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
            new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active,
                AllowedAudiences = new[] { audience },
                IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
                {
                  new X509CertificateSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, certificate),
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

I can get a Bearer token from my IDP and test it in [jwt.io](http://jwt.io) with the following result:

[image: Verified token]

`Issuer` matches from code to verified token.

`ClientId` matches from code to verified token (`sub`).

`Audience` matches from code to verified token.

For some reason - the token is however rejected (401 Unauthorized) on every request and I just can´t get my head around why. My request includes the `Authorization` header with the same bearer token I can verify using `jwt.io` (`Bearer ey..`). If it makes any difference I use [Auth0](http://auth0.com). I can also mention that I have tried downloading the public cert and using the file instead of just using the public key string with the same result.

Comment: Your credentials aren't entirely obfuscated in your image; it's possible to read the key, were someone so inclined. I'd suggest revoking those tokens if they're still in circulation, if you haven't already.

Comment: This was actually just a sample project and the keys expired a long time ago, but still, thank you for the concern ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `TokenValidationParameters` property of the `JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions` instance helped the issue:

```
private static void ConfigureAuthentication(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var issuer = "<<MyIssuer>>";
    var audience = "<<MyAudience>>";

    const string publicKeyBase64 = "<<MyPublicKeyBase64>>";

    var certificate = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(publicKeyBase64));

    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
        new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active,
            AllowedAudiences = new[] { audience },
            IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
            {
              new X509CertificateSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, certificate),
            },
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (a, b, c, d) => new X509SecurityKey(certificate),
                ValidAudience = audience,
                ValidIssuer = issuer
            }           
        }
    );
}
```